# Selenium+AutoIt - send commands to execute in Remote Desktop

Tags: selenium, automation, autoit

I am trying to automate non-browser based functionality (thick client application - Delphi based), web-based application(new java application) and opted to use Selenium + AutoIt for this. I need to compare data displayed in both applications for one particular user.

To access the thick client application, I need to use Remote Desktop Connection. I was able to connect to the remote desktop through selenium+autoit but not able to send any commands to the remote machine. If anyone is aware of the solution please help.

Following is the code I used.

```
import java.io.File;
import autoitx4java.AutoItX;
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

public class sampleTest {

  static String rdcPwd = "password";
  static String remoteComputerName = "computername";
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
    jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("MSTSC.EXE");
    x.winActivate("Remote Desktop Connection");
    x.winWaitActive("Remote Desktop Connection");
    x.controlClick("Remote Desktop Connection", "Co&nnect", "1");
    Thread.sleep(15000);
    x.send(rdcPwd);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    x.controlClick("Windows Security", "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2;]");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    x.send("#r");      // Not Working
    x.run("explorer.exe");  //Not Working
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: What part of that code is Selenium?

Comment: You have to find the pid for mstsc.exe and then using `StdinWrite($pid,$cmd)` you can send the commands to that process.